Is it terribly bad to limit HTTP connection reuse or is .NET (Core) HttpClient broken from the start?
In the transition from .NET Framework to .NET (formerly .NET Core), Microsoft has introduced a new HTTP client, called System.Net.Http.HttpClient and System.Net.HttpWebRequest is now marked as obsolete.
While troubleshooting my application that uses a mixture of these, I discovered that HttpClient does not respect the TTL from DNS. Nowadays there is an official solution, to set a maximum lifetime on all connections. This looks crazy to me because:

the lifetime is determined by the developer, not DNS. So if a service provider wants to change its TTL, it doesn't catch it.
the connection is closed and recreated, even if the DNS is not changed. Just because the TTL is 5 minutes, it does not mean that there will be a new IP every 5 minutes.

Before this solution, there was no solution at all in .NET Core as far as I know, but you could adjust ServicePoint objects in .NET Framework.
Feels like Microsoft launched new HTTP client, baked it into their new SDKs, promoted it heavily, made the old one obsolete, and accidentally forgot about DNS.
In my scenario we have continious background jobs (Azure WebJobs), calling out to a handful of HTTP APIs, running on a VM (Azure App Service) so we have the possibility to reuse connections more than if we were using serverless compute.
Seems like a general error. Have I misunderstood something? Am I making a mountain out of a molehill?
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines

Microsoft has introduced a new HTTP client, called System.Net.Http.HttpClient. HttpClient was introduced with .Net Framework 4.5. That was 2010. That isn't new. This question is more on-topic for Stack Overflow.

have you tried WebClient? a bit older but might work

Not looking for a code fix. I am a developer looking for a opinion on how serious this deficiency in .NET is, from the sys admin community.
